# Validation errors with any() when upgrading to Mockito 2.21

Tags: java, mockito

The following code throws a validation error and says it doesn't like the use of `any()` in my `@Test` method:

```
@Test
public void testBatchCreate() {
    CreateResponse createResponse = new 
        CreateResponse(HttpStatus.S_201_CREATED);
    when(_devService.batchCreate(any()))
        .thenReturn(Task.value(new BatchCreateResult<>(Collections.singletonList(createResponse))));
}
```

The validation error is

```
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

My question is, this does seem to be within the mock/stub portion of the test, so I'm confused why this validation error is getting thrown or how to refactor this test properly.

Comment: How is `_devService` defined?

Comment: @LukeWoodward it's defined as a private Mock. `@Mock
  private DeveloperService _devService;`

Comment: Try to add some more informations to your question. An [mre] would be nice, the code of whatever `devService` is and the complete stacktrace.